# Is it possible to edit Logic app file system or SFTP trigger conditions to fire a logic app based on filename or extension?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I would like to trigger my logic app which is reading files from SFTP only if files with a certain name or extension are uploaded/modified. I want to avoid using multiple actions to check file name. Is there any possible way to edit File System/SFTP trigger conditions to check file name and accordingly trigger the logic app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could. If you want to use trigger condition to check the file name, you have to use  [When a file is added or modified (properties only)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/ftpconnector/#when-a-file-is-added-or-modified-(properties-only)).

I test the one without properties only, I check the output is there any property to get the file name, and then I use `@equals('47.txt',trigger()['outputs']['headers']['x-ms-file-name'])` as trigger condition, however I get this error message.

[image]

So this trigger could not meet your requirement. Then I test with properties only, this output body has a property `Displayname` to get the file name. So I changed the codition to `@equals('47.txt',trigger()['outputs']['body']['DisplayName'])`, with this codition, if the filename doesn't equal, it will be triggered, however it won't fired it.

[image]

Hope this could help you.